# Computing trig integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int^{1}_{-1}(4x+1)\sin(x^2+x)\cos(x^2)dx$$I tried using substitution, however it made it seem more challenging than it had to be.  Do we first rearrange the equation, perhaps $\sin(x^2)+\sin(x)$?

...

$$\int^{1}_{-1}(4x+1)\frac{1}{2}[\sin(2x^2+x)+\sin(x)]$$ Now with $u=2x^2+x,du=4x+1$ there must be an easy way.  Does it not further compute to $$\frac{1}{2}\int^{3}_{1}\sin(u)+sin(?)$$
Or expand like suggest below,then integrate: $$\frac{1}{2}\int^{1}_{-1}[(4x)\sin(2x^2+x)+\sin(2x^2+x)+(4x)\sin(x)+sin(x)]$$

Comment: see if [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4J0u1lcIR84/UyutCnr73oI/AAAAAAAAARs/Rq0V7JT6ZRk/s1600/img1.gif) trig identity helps $$\sin(x^2+x)\cos(x^2) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin(2x^2+x)+\sin(x))$$

Comment: Is it a duplicate? It seems to me to have already seen such question, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I agree. isn't half(being modest) of integration a duplicate?

Comment: @ganeshie8 Hey, that works well, but I come to $\frac1{2}\int^{3}_{1}\sin(u)+\sin(u-2x^2)$, do I split the $\sin$ into $\sin(u)-\sin(2x^2)$?

Comment: @Stack Can you show your work? I don't believe you did that right. The integral can't have 2 different variables.

Comment: @Dylan damn I made a typo in the question, should be $(4x+1)$

Comment: @Stack Notice that $\frac{d}{dx}(2x^2 + x) = 4x + 1$

Comment: @Dylan So, $\sin(u) + \sin(?)$ If $u=2x^2+x$, $x=u-2x^2$ no?

Comment: Again, you have to express everything in terms of one variable. If we let $u = 2x^2 + x$, then $du = (4x+1)\,dx$ and $$\int\sin(2x^2+x)\cdot(4x+1)\,dx = \int \sin u \,du$$

Answer (score 2):

As complicated the integral is, I believe the trick here is to realize that the integral of f(x), where f(x) is odd, is:

$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx =0$

From the original problem we can conclude the following:

$\int_{-1}^1 (4x-1)sin(x^2+x)cos(x^2)dx$
$= \int_{-1}^1 (4x-1) ( sin(x^2)cos(x)+cos(x^2)sin(x) ) cos(x^2) dx$

$= \int_{-1}^1 ( 4xcos(x^2)sin(x^2)cos(x) + 4xcos^2(x^2)sinx -cos(x^2)sin(x^2)cosx - cos^2(x^2)sinx ) dx$

Let 
$g(x)= 4xcos(x^2)sin(x^2)cos(x)$ , and note how it is an *odd function*.
$m(x)= 4xcos^2(x^2)sinx$, and note how it is an *even function*.
$n(x)= cos(x^2)sin(x^2)cosx$, and note how it is an *even function*.
$p(x)= cos^2(x^2)sinx$, and note how it is an *odd function*.

So the integral now becomes:

$ \int_{-1}^1 g(x) dx + \int_{-1}^1 m(x) dx - \int_{-1}^1 n(x) dx - \int_{-1}^1 p(x) dx$

$\to \int_{-1}^1 m(x) dx - \int_{-1}^1 n(x) dx$

I get stuck here, maybe someone else can jump in. I hope this has helped a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\sin(x^2+x)\cos(x^2) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(x)+\sin(2x^2+x)\right)\tag{1}$$
our integral equals:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}(4x+1)\sin x\,dx +\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}(4x+1)\sin(2x^2+x)\,dx\tag{2} $$
or just:
$$ 2\int_{-1}^{1}x\sin x\,dx -\left.\cos(2x^2+x)\right|_{-1}^{1}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: It may not have been a typo, but the problem as originally stated could not be easily evaluated. The modified problem is, and your answer handles it with a slight change.

Comment: nice, but there is no easy way with a substitution?

Comment: @Stack: in this case a substitution just makes everything more complicated. Integration by parts works just fine, why do you need something else?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio no, but I can't seem to get from your step (2) to (3)

Comment: @Stack: a sine vanishes because the integral of an integrable odd function over a symmetric domain is zero. For the last term it is enough to recall that: $$\int f'(x) \sin(f(x))\,dx = -\cos(f(x))$$ with $f(x)=2x^2+x$.

Answer (score 0):

prove that the integrand is equals to $$\frac{1}{2} \left(4 x \sin \left(2 x^2+x\right)-\sin \left(2 x^2+x\right)+4 x
   \sin (x)-\sin (x)\right)$$ and now you can integrate